# How to configure tslint to throw an error for using an undeclared variable

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using Typescript in Angular context. I would like to configure my tslint to catch typos. For example in my app-component.ts I've the following code:

```
export class AppComponent {
public heroes = HEROES;
}
```

Then in my template I've

```
 <li *ngFor="let hero of heros">
```

Use of "heroes" in my template is a typo. I believe compiler is declaring a new variable I would like to configure TSLint to throw an error. 
I am using default tslint configuration that comes with Angular CLI.